Django group by after annotate does not work
I have the following Django models:
class Order(models.Model):
    ...
    org_slug = models.CharField()

class ProductToOrder(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qty = models.IntegerField()
    cost = models.FloatField()

I need to sum Orders that grouped by on org_slug and it must have sum of orders that have only one ProductToOrder and ProductToOrder.qty=1
I'm trying to do it in this way
        orders = Order.objects.filter(
            some_filter_here
        ).values('org_slug').annotate(
            order_sum=Subquery(Order.objects.filter(
                org_slug=OuterRef('org_slug')).annotate(
                    product_count=Coalesce(Sum('producttoorder__qty'), 1)
        ).filter(product_count=1).values('org_slug').annotate(
            sum=Sum('producttoorder__cost')
        ).values('sum')[:1]))

But it returns queryset of all orders. For example, if I have 1000 orders and 2 org_slugs, I need to get 2 objects in the query list but it returns 1000. This line where I'm trying to group by queryset in the following Subquery does not work:
.filter(product_count=1).values('org_slug')

I'm tried a lot of different querysets to fix it but it didn't give me any positive result. I see only one way to fix it, I need to create qty field in Order model but I hope, there are other ways to fix it. Can anybody help me with it?

So what should happen if an Order has no ProductToOrders with qty=1, or multiple?

What is the difference between Order and AppsOrder?

If Order has no ProductToOrder with qty=1 or it has multiple ProductToOrder then we don't need to use them in statistics. I use this filter .filter(product_count=1) to sum only orders where ProductToOrder.qty=1. Order and AppsOrder are the same, I just renamed model but forgot rename it in one place of code (I've already renamed it).

I think you are overcomplicating things. You can work with:
from django.db.models import Sum

Order.objects.filter(org_slug=my_slug, producttoorder__qty=1).annotate(
    total=Sum('producttoorder__cost')
)
This will retrieve the Order objects with org_slug=my_slug, and sum up the cost of all related ProductToOrders.
There is however a caveat here: it will also sum up if there are multiple ProductToOrders with qty=1. If you want to omit these, we can work with:
from django.db.models import Count, Exists, OuterRef, Sum

Order.objects.filter(
    ~Exists(ProductToOrder.objects.filter(~Q(qty=1), order_id=OuterRef('pk'))),
    org_slug=my_slug,
    producttoorder__qty=1,
).annotate(total=Sum('producttoorder__cost'), num=Count('producttoorder')).filter(
    num=1
)
This will thus only consider Orders with one ProductToOrder that has qty=1.

Thank you for your answer. There is one problem with this solution, it will work only for one particular org_slug, and if we have hundred org_slugs, we need to make hundred requests to database in loop to extract all of them. It will be really slow.

@UserDev: so you aggregate per org_slug, or per Order?

I need to aggregate per org_slug. For example, if I have 1000 orders with 2 different org_slugs, the result must be the list with 2 elements. Your solution will return 1 element. My solution will return 1000 elements, it just sum to all orders and doesn't apply group by .values('org_slug').

@UserDev: and thus only work with Orders for that org_slug with exactly one OrderToProduct with qty=1?

Yes, we must filter to sum only orders that have only one ProductToOrder with qty = 1
